# Catalyst::Controller::FormBuilder view does not render input fields

Tags: perl, catalyst, formbuilder

I'm trying to use the example view in CPAN for Catalyst::Controller::FormBuilder, which looks like this:

```
<!-- root/src/books/edit.tt -->
<head>
  <title>[% formbuilder.title %]</title>
  [% formbuilder.jshead %]<!-- javascript -->
</head>
 <body>
  [% formbuilder.start -%]
  <div id="form">
    [% FOREACH field IN formbuilder.fields -%]
    <p>
        <label>
           <span [% IF field.required %]class="required"[%END%]>[%field.label%]</span>
        </label>
      [% field.field %]
      [% IF field.invalid -%]
          <span class="error">
              Missing or invalid entry, please try again.
          </span>
      [% END %]
      </p>
    [% END %]
    <div id="submit">[% formbuilder.submit %]</div>
    <div id="reset">[% formbuilder.reset %]</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  [% formbuilder.end -%]
</body>
```

The problem is I do get the field labels, but not the input fields, on my page: did anybody had this problem, before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: there is an error in the docs:

```
[% field.field %]
```

should read as

```
[% field.tag %]
```

...